# Evaluate second regex after one regex pass

Tags: regex

I want to grab value after one regex is passed. The sample is

```
My test string is ##[FirstVal][SecondVal]##
```

I want to grab `FirstVal` and `SecondVal`.

I have tried `\#\#(.*?)\#\#` pattern but only return `[FirstVal][SecondVal]`.

Is it possible to evaluate result of one regex and apply another regex?

Comment: There are workarounds for that, but what is your regex flavor? You can easily do that in C# with a CaptureCollection, in PCRE and some others, you may use `\G` operator to set up a custom boundary.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I want to match FirstVal and SecondVal from string ##[FirstVal][SecondVal]##.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you provide an example with C#. I am quite familiar with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, you may use a capture stack to grab all the repeated captures.

A regex like

```
##(?:\[([^][]*)])+##
```

will find `##`, then match and capture any amount of strings like `[` + `texts-with-no-brackets` + `]` and all these `texts-with-no-brackets` will be pushed into a *CaptureCollection* that is associated with capture group 1.

See the [regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%23%28%3F%3A%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%29%5D%29%2B%23%23&i=My%20test%20string%20is%20%23%23%5BFirstVal%5D%5BSecondVal%5D%23%23)

[image]

In C#, you would use the following code:

```
var s = "My test string is ##[FirstVal][SecondVal]##";
var myvalues = Regex.Matches(s, @"##(?:\[([^][]*)])+##")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .SelectMany(m => m.Groups[1].Captures
          .Cast<Capture>()
          .Select(t => t.Value));
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myvalues));
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/4yuw3n)

Mind you can do [a similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416911/regex-capturing-group-within-non-capturing-group/39418673#39418673) with **Python PyPi `regex` module**.

Answer (score 0):

It will make a difference as to what programming language you are using as the modules might vary slightly. I used python for my solution, since you didn't specify what language you were using, and you could use two parentheses with the #'s on either side and using an escape character to make regex not match the square braces (ie. `\[(\w+)\]`. Where in the python re module the `\w` represents the denotation for `a-zA-Z0-9_`.

```
import re
data = "##[FirstVal][SecondVal]##"
x = re.search(r'##\[(\w+)\]\[(\w+)\]', data)
print(x.groups())
```

Which prints `('FirstVal', 'SecondVal')`

Comment: Its not working at all. It returns `##[FirstVal][SecondVal]' as result.

Comment: My solution works perfectly fine in **Python 3.x**, I have no idea how your regex behaves.